# App is unable to start

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Log details are :

> >
>                      **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null**
>                         at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38)
>                         at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155)
>                         at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
>                         at **com.venkatesh.autocompletetextviewdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)**
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4291 SIG: 9 Application terminated.

Now Lotcat is :
11-19 21:13:21.648 3567-3567/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-19 21:13:21.648 3567-3567/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-19 21:13:22.714 3578-3578/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
11-19 21:13:25.940 2026-2237/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Unrecognised action provided: android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED
11-19 21:13:26.626 3611-3611/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
11-19 21:13:26.626 3611-3611/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
11-19 21:17:07.624 1520-1607/system_process E/wifi: getStaticLongField sWifiHalHandle 0x7f3999c273d0
11-19 21:17:07.624 1520-1607/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: cancelDelayedScan -> 1

```
                                                            [ 11-19 21:17:07.643  1520: 1548 D/         ]
                                                            HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f3994836710, tid 1548


                                                            [ 11-19 21:17:07.651  1520: 1548 W/         ]
                                                            Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1
```

11-19 21:17:07.664 1520-1607/system_process E/WifiStateMachine: cancelDelayedScan -> 2
11-19 21:17:07.806 1130-1130/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1130: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-19 21:17:08.488 1520-1549/system_process E/libsuspend: Error writing to /sys/power/wakeup_count: Invalid argument
11-19 21:17:08.510 1130-1130/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1130: eglCreateSyncKHR(1865): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
11-19 21:17:08.616 1520-1549/system_process E/libsuspend: Error writing to /sys/power/state: Device or resource busy

```js
package com.venkatesh.autocompletetextviewdemo;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final DBHelper mydb = new DBHelper(this);
         final String[] mydata = mydb.SelectAllData();
         final AutoCompleteTextView autoCom = findViewById(R.id.ACtextview);
         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, mydata);

        autoCom.setThreshold(1);   /** will start working form first character. */
        autoCom.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

```css
public String[] SelectAllData(){
        try {
            String arrData[] = null;
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db=this.getReadableDatabase();
            String SQLstr = " Select * From " + MANF_TABLE_NAME;
                Cursor cursor =db.rawQuery(SQLstr,null);

                 if (cursor != null)
                 {

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        arrData = new String[cursor.getCount()];
                        int i = 0 ;
                        do {
                            arrData[i] = cursor.getString(1) ;
                            System.out.print(arrData[i]);
                            i++;

                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                 }

               cursor.close();
                 return  arrData;

        } catch ( Exception e ) {

           return null;

        }
    }
```

Comment: More details needed regarding your environment.

Comment: What SDK are you using?

Comment: See your MainActivity.java, line number 20. It is null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to be null pointer exception, There which you defined an array, do you connect that array to a list view, or another view or something? ... if so, check and make sure you connected that view from your `XML` file, to your Java code, by using the `findViewById();`method, before using that view. If the code which is using those views is in another method rather than `onCreate` don't forget to declare the view or sth, inside the class and before the onCreat method, example :`private ListView mylist;`or whatever, otherwise codes inside other methods can't reach those views.